# Form of Jensen's Inequality for Two Convex Functions

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose two convex functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that are everywhere strictly positive and are such that $g^{-1}(f(x))$ is also convex ($g$ is convex with respect to $f$). Let $x$ be a random variable in $L^1$. Jensen's inequality can be used to show:

$$\frac {E[f(x)]}{f(E[x])} \ge 1$$

I would like to show:

$$\frac {E[g(x)]}{g(E[x])} \ge \frac {E[f(x)]}{f(E[x])}$$

Is this true? If not, what about showing:

$$\frac {E[f(x^n)]}{f(E[x^n])} \ge \frac {E[f(x)]}{f(E[x])}$$

where $n > 1$?